# React update state based on value from e.target

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following method which works fine, however I was hoping to find

```
...
  handleClick = (e) => {
    this.props.onClick()

    if(this.props.getAnswer(e)) {
      console.log('correct')
      //this.setState({ [this.state.button+ e.target.getAttribute('data-option')]: 'correct' });
      if(e.target.getAttribute('data-option') == 1){
        this.setState({
          button1: 'correct'
        })
      }
      if(e.target.getAttribute('data-option') == 2){
        this.setState({
          button2: 'correct'
        })
      }
      if(e.target.getAttribute('data-option') == 3){
        this.setState({
          button3: 'correct'
        })
      }
      if(e.target.getAttribute('data-option') == 4){
        this.setState({
          button4: 'correct'
        })
      }
    }
  }
...
```

would it be possible to do something like this?

```
    this.setState({
      button[e.target.getAttribute('data-option')]: 'correct'
    })
```

obviously this doesn't work but I didn't want to repeat unnecessary if statements. The "data-option" attr returns an integer so I wanted to use that to update the state property dynamically instead of button1, button2, button3 .....

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and very nearly like you have:

```
this.setState({
    ["button" + e.target.getAttribute('data-option')]: 'correct'
});
```

That assumes the value is 1, 2, 3, or 4 (whereas your current code doesn't). If it may not be, we need a guard:

```
var option = e.target.getAttribute('data-option');
if (option >= 1 && option <= 4) { // Coerces to number, NaN won't match
    this.setState({
        ["button" + option]: 'correct'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.setState({
    ["button"+e.target.getAttribute('data-option')] : 'correct'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ES6 template literal:

```
this.setState({
  [`button${e.target.getAttribute('data-option')}`]: 'correct'
});
```

Edit: use brackets for computed property name, without brackets you would get SyntaxError: expected property name, got template literal. See [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)'s answer, it's the best one so far.

Comment: *"You can use ES6 template literal"* No, you can't -- at least, not as shown above. You need to use a computed property name as in the previous answers.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder. It's the second time I'm making this mistake in my answer, maybe I'll finally get it ;)